# OnSaveSucces page redirection

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to redirect(stay) to CREATE_PAGE in Angular/TypeScript when inserting new item here is the code in ts file.. I've tried using window.open and href function but didin't have luck, if you have suggestions please answer :)

```js
    private onSaveSuccess(result: WorkingOrderItems) {
        // this.spinner.hide();
        this.isSaving = false;
        console.log('IN ON SUCCESS');
        if (this.isCreatePage) {
            console.log('IS CREATE');
            // this.workingOrderItemsService.loadWorkingOrderItemsPageEmitter.emit({ id: result.id, shouldRouteToDetails: false });
            this.workingOrderItemsService.changeSelectedWorkingOrderItemsEmitter.emit();
            this.workingOrderItemsService.changePageTypeEmitter.emit(CREATE_PAGE);
            // this.workingOrderItems = {};
            location.reload()
            window.open('working-order-items-create')

        } else {
            console.log('NOT CREATE');
            this.workingOrderItemsService.loadWorkingOrderItemsPageEmitter.emit(result.id);
            this.router.navigate([this.rootRoute], {
                queryParams: {
                    activeTab: this.tabName,
                    tabMode: DETAILS_PAGE,
                    id: result.id
                }
            });
        }
        this.spinner.hide();
  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody need "redirect" to a page and nobody need "location.reload()" -you're loading again the whole page-. The router.navigate is `router.navigate([path],...` where path is a string -or a variable-. If you're using a Subject, subscribe to it in your ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.workingOrderItemsService.changePageTypeEmitter.subscribe(res=>{
   ...do something when received this..
  })
}
```